# Copying ssh key from windows machine to windows server 2019

Tags: ssh, server, openssh, windows-server

I've been trying to get access to Windows Server 2019 without password through OpenSSH protocol.
So I've created new key which I need it to be copied to the Windows Server, I've tried this:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@server
```

But I get this after entering correct password:

```
'exec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

My issue is how to transfer key from one windows machine(using gitbash, WSL, powershell or whatever)
to Windows Server 2019 location of authorized keys if I am not mistaken.

I am desperate enough to do it manually but location of those keys is mystery to me, do I need to set something on Windows Server first so that it can accept keys for authentication ?

What is the alternative on ssh-copy-id from Windows machine to Windows Server 2019 ?

**Found solution:**
Followed this helpful youtube guide, props to the
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cs3wBl_mMH0&ab_channel=IT%2FOpsTalk-Deprecated-SeeChannelDescription

Also, installing OpenSSHUtils worked with:

```
Install-Module -Name OpenSSHUtils -RequiredVersion 0.0.2.0 -Scope AllUsers
```

Also this guide helped:

https://www.cloudsma.com/2018/03/installing-powershell-modules-on/

My server didn't have access so I manually copied file from:
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules to the server's:
Server:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

Answer (score 2):

First, this error message is followed by [`microsoft/vscode-remote-release` issue 25](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/25)

Current workaround (the context is VSCode, but should apply also for regular SSH connection):

> Also, for anyone else here that loves their bash on windows but still wants to be able to use VSCode remote, the workaround I have currently setup is to use an `autorun.cmd` deployed on the servers that detects when an SSH connection is coming in and has a terminal allocated:

```sh
@echo off

if defined SSH_CLIENT (
    :: check if we've got a terminal hooked up; if not, don't run bash.exe
    C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "if [ -t 1 ]; then exit 1; fi"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login
        exit
    )
)
```

> This is known to work with Cygwin bash, unsure about bash that ships with windows; I imagine it's very sensitive to how the TTY code works internally.
> This way, launching `cmd.exe` works normally, using VSCode (because it does not allocate a PTY) works normally, but SSH'ing into the machine launches bash.exe.

I suspect it would also work using the `bash.exe` which comes with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), should it be installed on the target server.

The destination file should be on the server:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\authorized_keys
```

If you can do it manually, simply try and `scp` it instead of using `ssh-copy-id`

```
scp user@server:C:/Users/<user>/.ssh/authorized_key authorized_key 
# manual and local edit to add the public key
scp authorized_key  user@server:C:/Users/<user>/.ssh/authorized_key
```

(again, I would use the scp.exe coming with Git For Windows, installed this time locally)

Comment: The `bash` that ships in Windows 10 usually points to your default WSL distro. Depending on your configuration on `Path`, this might point to either Cygwin or Git Bash.

Comment: @AndreiJirohEugenioHalili But Cygwin is not shipped with Windows 10, is it?

Answer (score 1):

**Found solution:**
Followed this helpful youtube guide, props to the
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cs3wBl_mMH0&ab_channel=IT%2FOpsTalk-Deprecated-SeeChannelDescription

Also, installing OpenSSHUtils worked with:

```
Install-Module -Name OpenSSHUtils -RequiredVersion 0.0.2.0 -Scope AllUsers
```

Also this guide helped:

https://www.cloudsma.com/2018/03/installing-powershell-modules-on/

My server didn't have access so I manually copied file from:
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules to the server's:
Server:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules